# How to find the largest number in an array element in swift?

Tags: arrays, max

How to find the largest number in an array element in swift without using inbuilt function ?

```
// Given:

let array = [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4]

// Make it temp largest element = 0
var largest = 0

// iterate each element in array  
    for newArr in array
    {
        if (newArr > largest)
        {
            largest = newArr
        }
    }

print(largest)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? It already worked.